# Fade in element on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I can't seem to get a fade in on scroll to work. I want a simple div to fade in when i scroll down to it.

Here is the code I have:

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.fadeInBlock').each(function(i) {
      var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

      /* Adjust the "200" to either have a delay or that the content starts fading a bit before you reach it  */
      bottom_of_window = bottom_of_window + 500;

      if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
        $(this).animate({
          'opacity': '1'
        }, 500);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.fadeInBlock {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="fadeInBlock">Fade In 01</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please convert your code into a JSFiddle or CodePen example? Thanks.

Comment: As you scroll up and down, your `scroll` event is called hundreds of times. You need to call it only once (after an elapsed time, using `setTimeout`). Also, there is no need to use the jquery `animate`. Better use a CSS3 opacity transition for that, instead.

Comment: Also if the event repeat so many times, the animation queue gets very long and is FIFO so it creates behaviors that you don't want, like blinking or not rendering the element...

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop()` will tell you the scroll height in pixels. So you can use this in an if statement to manipulate the element at different scroll heights.